# Can I use CanCan to get around a 'nil' current_user on a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

So on the `index` view for my `Items` controller, I have some references to `current_user`.

Now, when I browse to `/items` when not logged in, I get this error:

> NoMethodError at /items undefined method `items' for nil:NilClass

This is around this line in my `Items#Index` in my `ItemsController.rb`

```
@items = current_user.items.all
```

I know that this obviously means that there is a `nil` value returned when `items` is looked up on a non-logged in user, naturally that makes sense because a non logged in user doesn't have any items (per the business logic of the app - you have to be logged in).

This is what my `ability.rb` looks like:

```
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    alias_action :create, :read, :update, :destroy, :to => :crud
    alias_action :create, :update, :destroy, :to => :cud

    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      cannot :cud, Item
      can :read, Item
      cannot :read, :items
    end

    if user.has_role? :seller
      can :cud, Item, :user_id => user.id
      can :read, Item
    end

    if user.has_role? :buyer
      can :read, Item
    end
  end
```

The reason the `else` branch of my `if` statement related to my `:admin` role looks so convoluted is because what should happen is all users (logged in or not) should be able to view each item record (`item:/id`). But, only a logged in user (of any role) should be able to view `/items` (i.e. `Item#index`) which customizes the results per the `current_user` scope.

Do I really have to put that assignment statement inside an `if` statement in my `ItemsController.rb`?

What am I missing?

**Edit 1**:

This is the top of my `ItemsController.rb`

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_filter :initialize_cart

  layout "item"
  # GET /items
  # GET /items.json
  def index
    #authorize! :index, @user, :message => "Rut row. Seems this door is locked and you don't have the key."
    if params[:tag]
      @items = current_user.items.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @items = current_user.items.all
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @items }
    end
  end
```

This is my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery 
  before_filter :initialize_cart

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to main_app.root_path, :alert => exception.message
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || signed_in_root_path(resource_or_scope)
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    request.referrer
  end

  private

  def initialize_cart
    if session[:cart_id]
      @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    else
      @cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    end
  end

end
```

**Edit 2:**

This is in my `views/items/index.html.erb`

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to item.name, item_path(item) %></td>
    <td><%= item.description.html_safe %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(item.price, precision: 2) %></td>
    <% if item.is_approved? %>
        <td><%= l item.approved_at, format: :custom %></td> 
    <% else %>
        <td>N/A</td>
    <% end %>
    <td><%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-edit'></i>".html_safe, edit_item_path(item) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i>".html_safe, item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete #{item.name}?" } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you put the part where you output the @items in html.erb?

Comment: what are the roles, just :admin, :buyer, and :seller? Updated my answer. check the ability logic.

Comment: @SteveWilhelm Yes just those 3 roles.

Comment: @JoseRamonCamacho Just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current ability logic allows anyone to call ItemsController#index (second line of the admin else section)

Updated: I think the following change to the ability logic should fix it (now with explicit show instead of read)

```
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    alias_action :create, :read, :update, :destroy, :to => :crud
    alias_action :create, :update, :destroy, :to => :cud

    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    end

    if user.has_role? :seller
      can :cud, Item, :user_id => user.id
      can :read, Item
    end

    if user.has_role? :buyer
      can :read, Item
    end

    # this is the default ability, essentially anyone, logged in or not,
    # will be able to access individual items via ItemsController#show
    # Cancan has aliases like :read that are for both 
    # index and show, but you can define rules on individual actions explicitly
    # (even actions that are not default Rails REST actions) 
    can :show, Item
  end
```

Comment: Yep...I added `load_and_authorize_resource` to the top. Will update the question with the top of my `ItemsController.rb`

Comment: So All you did was pulled the `can :read, Item` out of the `else` branch of the `admin` role `if` statement right? If so...then yeh, this doesn't work.

Comment: I think both this and @zeantsoi's solution were going to work. I personally like having the abilities define what you can do. This initialize now cascades down from most access to least.

Comment: Can you update your answer to draw attention to the fact that you used `show` and not `read` and why - so someone else can understand it easily.

Comment: I agree with your approach, and I commented on @zeantosi's own too. His last change was likely to work, but I tested yours first. Plus, I prefer this one because I don't have to add any exceptions to the `load_and_authorize_resource` on my `ItemsController` with your version. Feels more lightweight to me.

Comment: @marcamillion, you _don't_ need to declare any exceptions in either answer you've cited. You may want to read [this commentary](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/302#comment_863142) by CanCan's author regarding the use of convenience aliases. Based on this discussion, I think it's more foolproof to declare custom aliases than to rely on the catch-all convenience aliases.

Answer (score 1):

You can specifically target the `Items#index` controller action for authorization by adding the following to the top of your `ItemsController` file:

```
# app/controllers/items_controller.rb
load_and_authorize_resource :only => [:index]
```

This prevents unauthorized users from accessing the `index` action, but not the `show` action (or any other controller action not declared in the array).

**UPDATE**:

In your `ability.rb`, you'll want to [alias](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Action-Aliases) a rule permitting (or preventing) access to the `index` and `show` actions:

```
# app/models/ability.rb
alias_action :index, :to => :read_index
alias_action :show, :to => :read_show

if user.has_role? :admin
  can :manage, :all
else
  cannot :cud, Item
  can :read_show, Item
  cannot :read_index, Item
end
```

**EXPLANATION**:

I understand why it might seem that `can :read, Item` restricts access *only* to the `show` action, but this is not the case. According to the [CanCan's author](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Action-Aliases), the library provides the following convenience alias:

```
alias_action :index, :show, :to => :read
```

This means that the `read` alias encompasses *both* the `show` **and** `index` actions. Thus, in declaring `can :read, Item`, you're permitting non-logged in users to access both actions. Then, because CanCan assigns privileges upon classes, rather on symbols, the declaration `cannot :read, :items` doesn't actually restrict access to anything.

In order to permit access to the `show` action, but prohibit access to the `index` action, you need to alias them separately and invoke them as I've demonstrated above.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. It doesn't seem to work for this issue though.

Comment: Please see my update. It includes modifications to `ability.rb` required to permit access to the `show` action, but not the `index` action.

Comment: So with the changes to the `admin` role, do I have to specify the action in the `load_and_authorize_resource` still?

Comment: You should not need to specify the action, since permissions for both logged in user and non-logged in users are addressed for both the `show` and `index` actions. That said, I'll leave my initial answer up for posterity and the possible benefit of future users.

Comment: you still need to authorize in some way the methods in a controller. See https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions for details.

Comment: You were right in your last explanation @zeantsoi. By breaking out the `show` & `index` actions. That would have done it. I tried Steve's answer first and that has solved it. So thanks much.

Comment: @SteveWilhelm, declaring `load_and_authorize_resource` will apply authorization for __all__ actions in the controller.

Comment: @marcamillion, based on [this commentary](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/302#comment_863142) from the author of CanCan, I believe it's best to explicitly declare individual aliases, rather than relying on the `read` catch-all. Ryan alludes to the declaration of `read` as being confusing, and goes as far to remove it from internal invocations.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with:

```
<% if can? :read, @items %>
  @items.each...
  ...
<% end %>
```

hope it helps you

Comment: Was hoping to be able to avoid having to clutter the view like this. The issue is the entire view - not just 1 line.

Comment: have you tried with a verification in the controller, if curren_user.has_role? (invalid_role) redirect_to safe_place_path ... or it's necessary to load the items index view?

Comment: Yes it is neccessary to load the items index view.

Comment: then I think the best way to add conditions to the view is the way above, to every place that has the problem.

Comment: Definitely not. I have already solved it. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Doing can? calls in a view should be a red flag. Authorization should be completed at the controller level.